# Is it possible to implement the effect of turning pages of a book with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, plugins

Or is there a ready plugin that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/07/20/javascript-sprite-animation-using-jquery/) of just that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book flip slideshow using javascript.

[Book Flip Slideshow](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/bookflip.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Quick Googling uncovered this - see if it'll help you: [JavaScript Sprite Animation Using jQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-sprite-animation-using-jquery/)